# $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}$ extension

Tags: inequality

I just found an very interesting inequality during my learning! At first, I used: $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b} \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2$$

Then I found an another one:$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}}\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\Leftrightarrow (a-b)^4(a^2+b^2+ab)\geq0$$

After searching on AoPS, I found an new one too:

$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}\leq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}\Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$$

So I tried to prove these 2 inequalities:

P1: Let $a,b \geq 0,k\geq-1$, prove that: $$\sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}{2}} \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}$$

But is this inequality true? I can't answer that for myself so I posted it here, hope somebody can solve this problem. Thanks a lots!!!

$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}{2}} \leq \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}}$$
for $k \geq -1,n\geq0$

P2: Let: $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \geq 0$, $k\geq -1$, prove that:
$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{a_1^k+a_2^k+...+a_n^k}{n}}\leq \frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}$$

And like the P1, is it true if I change:$$\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n} \mapsto \frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+...+a_n^m}{a_1^{m-1}+a_2^{m-1}+...+a_n^{m-1}}$$ for $m\geq 1$.

And also, I found on AoPS that this is from Mildorf's lemma:

Let: $k \geq -1$. Then for all positive $a,b$, we get:$$\frac{(1+k)(a-b)^2+8ab}{4(a+b)}\geq \sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}{2}}$$

I tried to make: $$LHS-RHS=(a-b)^{2t}.A$$ with $A>0$

Thank you for all your helps! I hope all of them are true!

Comment: For $k=4$ and $n=2$ apparently there is a whole angular sector missing https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mbi8pqve92, e.g. $LHS(4.2,k=4)\approx 3.41 > RHS(4,2,n=2) \approx 3.33$ as a simple counter-example.

Comment: Do you think that there is a relationship between $n$ and $k$ :)